# Faster Items inside a ArrayList<T>

Tags: android, performance, arraylist, android-canvas

I'm write a little Plotter for my App.

The function need to much time, is there another way, to draw faster in Canvas ?

```
String auggabe = "x+2";
            float xMitte = step * (count_w/2); //stepp is 100px, count_w is 20
            float yMitte = step * (count_h/2);  //count_h is 10
            ArrayList<Float[]> yWerte = new ArrayList<>();
            for(float i = (count_w/2 * -1);i <= count_w/2; i = getF(i + 0.15f))
            {
                Log.d("FC", Float.toString(i));
                String a =  new math_compile(auggabe.replace("x", String.valueOf(i)), 0).getAufgabe();//is a class they give me the arithmetic problem value
                float y =  Float.parseFloat(a.replace(" ","")) ;
                yWerte.add(new Float[]{i, y*-1});
            }
```

this code is my Problem, its neet to long for 133 items
to draw belowe there

```
 for(int inde = 0; inde <= yWerte.size()-2; inde++)
            {
                Float[] xy = yWerte.get(inde);
                Float[] xyII = yWerte.get(inde + 1);
                canvas.drawLine((xy[0] * step) + xMitte, (xy[1] * step) + yMitte, (xyII[0] * step) + xMitte, (xyII[1] * step) + yMitte, fc);
            }
```

to round the float

```
private float getF(float y)
{
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    String twoDigitNum = df.format(y).replace(",",".");
    Log.d("getF", twoDigitNum);
    return Float.parseFloat(twoDigitNum);
}
```

Comment: Profile your app and point at specific problem in your code

Comment: The problem si not the ArrayList, it's the string parsing and formatting.

Comment: Also, the (un)boxing can degrade the performance. Use `float[]` instead of `Float`[].

Comment: `x+2` is an example?

Comment: yes, x+2 is an example to testing

Answer (score 1):

- Don't do allocations inside the draw. Do them as part of the initialization of your object, or as soon as you know what you will draw when receiving some data. Looks like the whole first part can be moved outside of your drawing code and recomputed only when it changes.
- Don't use a List for `yWerte`, you can do perfectly fine with an array. This will avoid the `get()` calls.
- Don't use `Float` where `float` would do perfectly fine. As others pointed out, the [boxing and unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) also hit performance.
- You can probably even pre-compute the position of each x,y coordinate from the lines you draw, and avoid the additional arithmetic operations in the `draw` method itself. This means basically moving everything outside of the draw and precalculating a `float[][]` array with the x,y coordinates for the lines.

Comment: there is my Code and when i'm finish, i post it again http://pastebin.com/cFg4YvCq

Comment: O, i have read a little bit about "the boxing and unboxing" it is to use not a cast and the currently datatype ?? Only

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this but I think defining the below variables outside the for loop" will results in some better performance, as they also will be generated for like 133 times...

```js
String a;
float y;
float[] xy;
float[] xyII;
```

Comment: Ok i try, wait 
i have looking at this page :http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/12/coding-for-performance-and-avoiding-garbage-collection-in-android/ 
but is wasn't helpful

Comment: and how to at a item i the Float[] ??

Answer (score 0):

// You are executing the first code block off the drawing thread, right?

One optimization I see is that each `xy` you use the exact same multiplications and additions so you can pre-compute those. Also, what other people here suggest about using primitive `float` is an extremely good idea. Also, use `List.toArray()` to obtain a primitive `float[][]` array:

```
// off-draw
yWerte.add(new float[]{i * step + xMitte, y * -1 * step + yMitte});
float[][] arrWerte = yWerte.toArray();

// draw
float[] xy = arrWerte[inde];
float[] xyII = arrWerte[inde + 1];
canvas.drawLine((xy[0], xy[1], xyII[0], xyII[1], fc);
```

Now, as for carrying variable declarations out of the cycle -- it's a good thing, but actually JIT will do that for you (*gurus, correct me if I'm wrong*), so you probably won't get any noticeable speed jump in any contemporary environment (any Android from 2.2 on)

Still, to be sure and also make your code look more hardcore as a side effect, here's an implementation of the cycle intended to be faster in non-JIT environments:

```
 // avoid property lookups using local vars
 int werteLength = arrWerte.length - 2;
 float[][] localArrWerte = arrWerte;

 for(int inde = 0; inde <= werteLength; inde++) {
     float[] xy = arrWerte[inde];
     float[] xyII = arrWerte[inde + 1];
     canvas.drawLine((xy[0], xy[1], xyII[0], xyII[1], fc);
 }
```

**PS** take a look at [android performance guide](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#Loops)

Comment: ok i have change a think, you can look there, is this so ok ? http://pastebin.com/mXDEDpqt

Comment: @DanielBaumertHackerOnBoard No mate, don't use iterators (foreach syntax), without JIT it's slower. But the reusage idea is pretty neat.

Comment: ah okey, i try programmed